# How to use Qt's QVector3D::unproject() function?

Tags: qt, opengl, qvector3d

I'm doing an opengl project in Qt with the new QOpenGLWidget class.
I'm just trying to get the opengl world coordinates of my mouse when I click.
I've found a lot of ways to do it but some were obsolete and the others don't work. Then I found the QVector3D::unproject() function but I don't get the right coordinates.
This is a part of my code so far :

```
QMatrix4x4 modelView;
modelView.setToIdentity();
modelView.lookAt(m_camera.getPosition(), m_camera.getTarget(), m_camera.getUp());

QMatrix4x4 projection;
projection.perspective(70.0, width() / height(), 0.1, 120.0);

GLint view[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &view[0]);

QVector3D worldPosition = QVector3D(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y(), 0).unproject(modelView, projection, QRect(view[0], view[1], view[2], view[3]));
qDebug() << worldPosition;
```

Do you know why I get (1.96532, -3.93444, 4.93216) where I should have (-0.5, -0.5, 0.0) ?

Comment: It is unclear what your modelview matrix actually looks like, but I find it quite unlikely that you should ger (-0.5, -0.5, 0.0). What makes you think that that should be the result?

Comment: I draw a triangles with the coordinates : GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
    }; and I know the position, target and vector up of my matrix so I know which corner of the triangle is (-0.5, -0.5, 0.0). There are the values : m_position = QVector3D(2.0, -4.0, 5.0);
    m_target = QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    m_up = QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); I've tried to change them in every possibilities but it's never what I expect

Comment: If your camera is at (2, -4, 5), looking at (0,0,0), and your near plane is 0.1 units in front of your camera, unprojecting a point at window space positions (x,y,0) - which lies on the near plane obviously - would end up on a plane perpendicular to the viewing direction, at 0.1 units distance in front of your camera, so (1.96532, -3.93444, 4.93216) sounds like a very plausible result. If you want the original vertex coordinates back, you can't just ignore the z coordinate.

Comment: I know, I already thought about it and I had changed my z coordinate with this result : with 0.5, I have a point at z=0. That makes sense because the near plane is at 0.1 (and I have change the camera position to (0, 0, 5) for easier testing). However, I get (-0.140625, 0.133333, 0) where it should be (-0.5, -0.5, 0.0).

Comment: I found out that what I need was the projected z coordinate to unproject the x and y but in order to get it, I need the unprojected x and y ... this is an infinite loop :p

Comment: Well, you of course need the window space  - "projected" - z coordinate.  It is usuallly stored in the depth buffer.